# C# Equivalent java code

Tags: c#, java

What is the equivalent for this C# code in Java?

```
string receivedData = …;
string splittedValues = receivedData.Split("&", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
Iterable<String> splitStrings = 
  Splitter.on('&').omitEmptyStrings().split(string);
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Answer (score 6):

`final String[] splittedValues = receivedData.replaceFirst("^&+","").split("&+");`

Comment: Failed for "&&sdfds". An empty string is in the result.

Comment: @nhahtdh You don't even need two && to get that.

Comment: @Joey: You sure you tested? Even without the trimming, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular code above, you can first:

- Remove leading/trailing tokens of the delimiter: `.replaceAll("(^&+|&+$)", "")`
- Split the string according to the delimiter: `.split("&+")`

Without the first step clean up, empty string will be in the result of splitting the string `"&&sdfds"` (leading delimiter).